# SSIS - Join two different tables from different servers

Tags: merge, ssis

I am trying to join data from two different databases, which have two different sets of data.

I have created the OLE DB source for both databases in dataflow (already set it up in connection manager). Also used SORT for both the OLE DB sources. Trying to use the MERGE to merge data so it looks like below but keeps getting a errors. Could this be down to the META data being set different from both tables?

```
**Table 1**
Student_ID | First Name
123        |Adam
134        |Joe
156        |Blogs


**Table 2**
Student_ID | Student Grade
123        |A
134        |B
156        |C

**What is required**
Student_ID | First Name |Student Grade
123        |Adam        |A
134        |Joe         |B
156        |Blogs       |C
```

Comment: User a Merge Join instead of a plain Merge.

Comment: What errors do you keep getting? `Could this be down to the META data being set different from both tables?` We won't be able to answer this unless you tell us what the metadata is. Show us what you've tried and the error messages you get.

Comment: Hi iv used the Converter to change the meta data and it seems to of solved the issue. Thanks for your help!